# Curious positive Impact of the batchsize on the training accuracy

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network

I have a question regarding the role of the batch size. My MLP model has 2 Dense-layers with "softmax" activation function:

```
# Creat my MLP MODEL:
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(units=64, input_dim  = 100))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Activation("softmax"))
model.add(Dense(units=64))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Activation("softmax"))
model.add(Dense(units=1))
```

[Green's Batchsize = 2, Pink's Batchsize = 8, Red's Batchsize = 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d7trd.png)

The dataset has 84000 samples. Each of the sample consists of 100 input values and 1 output value. Each of the sample describes a different subprocess, so the relationship between the samples do not exist. I have evaluated the training process with different batch_size. What is the reason that the training result looks better when the batch size is increased to 8? As far as I  Is there a relationship in my datasample that I was not aware of?

Comment: a side note: using softmax as an internal activation is extremely odd, unless this is for some very good, special reason you will be better off by substituting them with relus.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you are useing batchnorm, which, as the name suggests normalises samples based on statistics **in the batch**, thus it will work better if the sample size (batch size) is bigger. Apart from this higher batch size also means lower variance of your gradient estimator and is often good.